# Ef Core migrate enum to different enum type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-migrations

I have a code-first EF project with a table which uses the wrong enum in one column and need to migrate it using EF Migrations. I have to both rename the column, and then copy the old values to the new ones.

I know I can do it by simply writing an SQL script manually, but I was wondering if there is a way to let EF Migration do it automatically, "code-first" style?

The enums are stored as strings in the database, and they have slightly different members (but they have 1:1 mapping) i.e. the class is

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OldStatusType Status { get; set; }
}

public class DataMap : BaseConfiguration<Data>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Data> builder)
    {
        BaseConfigure(builder, "Datas", Schema.MySchema.ToString());

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        // map enum to string
        builder
            .Property(x => x.Status)
            .HasConversion<string>()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And now I need to change the class to

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NewStateType State { get; set; } // Status -> State
}
```

so that old Status values are mapped into new State values.

What is the correct approach for doing this in code-first migrations?

**[Update]**

To clarify, I tried doing this:

```
public partial class ChangeDataEnumType : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // rename Status to State
        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "Status",
            schema: "MySchema",
            table: "Data",
            newName: "State");
        
        // migrate 'Old' enum value to 'New'
        migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE [MySchema].[Data] SET [State] = 'New' WHERE [State] = 'Old'");
    }
}
```

but it fails with:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text']
      EXEC sp_rename N'[MySchema].[Data].[Status]', N'State', N'COLUMN';

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text']
      UPDATE [MySchema].[Data] SET [State] = 'New' WHERE [State] = 'Old'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Status'.
```

But the last query doesn't mention "Status" at all, it uses the new column name, so I am completely confused.

If I try these two statements one by one in SSMS (and then rollback), they work without issues.

Comment: Data migrations are never going to be automated by EF.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: sorry, I clarified my question, I wasn't expecting to get it fully automated, but just to get the answer on how it's supposed to be done, because it's failing and I don't see why.

Comment: "Invalid column name 'Status'" because you've already renamed it in some other way? Or you have a trigger or something?

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved in the same manner that you swap values of two variables because if your solution is already deployed and in use, you would probably want to persist preexisting data.

1. Create first migration to add the new column
2. In said migration, create a script populate the new column with values based off the old one.
3. Create second migration to remove the old column.

You could use automapper map to map one enum from another to add a bit of automation to this process and make the migration more readable.